# BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decode, 0, decode.length) return null

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bitmap

compileSdkVersion 29

java 1.8.0_13

kotlin plugin ver 1.4.0-release-studio4.0-1

my function

```
public static Bitmap base64ToBitmap(String imgString) {
        byte[] decode = Base64.decode(Uri.decode(imgString), Base64.DEFAULT |Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decode, 0, decode.length);
    }
```

the byteArray decode isn`t null , but BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray is null when I run this code.
Even more strange is that when I use debug evaluate expression ,it runs fine like the picture below.
This makes me feel very confused
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6P64.png)

Comment: What is/does Uri.decode() ?

Comment: Please post full code where you first encode a bitmap and then try to decode it back. bitmapToBase64().